# What is difference between unsafe code and unmanaged code in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

What is difference between unsafe code and unmanaged code in C#?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

managed code runs under supervision of the CLR (Common Language Runtime). This is responsible for things like memory management and garbage collection.

So unmanaged simply runs outside of the context of the CLR. unsafe is kind of "in between" managed and unmanaged. unsafe still runs under the CLR, but it will let you access memory directly through pointers.

Comment: What do you mean by "context"? With C++/CLI, you can mix managed and unmanaged (native) code in one assembly, in one process.

Comment: A C++/CLI assembly compiled with the /clr:safe option (safe mode) guarantees that IL code produced is verifiable, and type safe. Essentially, the safe assembly cannot contain any functionality that would belong in the C# unsafe block, such as pointer arithmetic. To use such functionality, must compile in pure mode with /clr:pure (the pure mode assembly is entirely IL, but may link against native dlls; linking statically against native DLLs in pure mode is not possible?) or mixed-mode /clr (which can not only link against native code but incorporate it into the produced assembly).

Answer (score 4):

Unsafe code in C# allows the use of pointers. In the context of the CLR, there is no unmanaged code in C#.

Comment: I've always understood 'unmanaged' code as code that doesn't execute in the context of the CLR... Basically like calls to C/C++ DLLs and such.

Comment: I totally agree. You won't be P/Invoking any C# DLLs though, just C/C++ ones as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Unsafe code runs inside the CLR while un-managed code runs outside the CLR.

An example of unsafe code would be:

```
unsafe class MyClass
{
    private int * intPtr;
}
```

You can use pointers anywhere in this class.

An example of unmanaged code is:

```
class MyClass
{
    [DllImport("someUnmanagedDll.dll")]
    static extern int UnManagedCodeMethod(string msg, string title);

    public static void Main() 
    {
        UnManagedCodeMethod("calling unmanaged code", "hi");
    }
}
```

It is not necessarily unmanaged code itself, but calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Unsafe - Code that can be outside the verifiable subset of CIL

Unmanaged - Code that is not managed by the runtime and is thus not visible
to the GC (for example a native compiled x86 function would be unmanaged.)

from: http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-15405.html

Comment: Yes, but you can also define extern functions with DLLImport attributes to bring in and hook to native DLLs; a class of extern function handles can be used as a managed "wrapper" to the native code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do inside of an unsafe context.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664769%28v=VS.71%29.aspx